# Using mysql_results to create a variable name

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm running a stored procedure that returns several rows, each row containing a PK counter and a phone number. I'm in need of a way to 'automate' the creation of variable names and assign those values to them. If I can't automate it, I at least need to create 3 different variables inside the while loop.

```
$rs = mysql_query("CALL GetUserNumbers('" . $_SESSION['UserID'] . "')");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
    $incrementingvariablename = row['phonenumber'];
    // something like $_1 = firstrow, $_2 = secondrow etc until all the rows have been read.
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arrays are good for this:

```
$incrementingvariablename[] = row['phonenumber'];
```

or

```
$incrementingvariablename[] = array('phone'=>row['phonenumber'],'counter'=>row['counter']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this php feature:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$$foo = 'Hello I am bar';

echo $bar; // Outputs 'Hello I am bar';
echo "\n";
```

Comment: This is just an extremely messy alternative to arrays.

Comment: Yeah, but it is what question author asks: how to dynamically create variables.

Comment: This is useful to know. Thanks a bunch. I wonder if it would work for values pulled from a query result set? even so though, the array method seems much more feasible.

Comment: In fact, the down vote is not fair: the answer is indeed correct given the question (but it was someone else who voted so). @Kulingar: result sets are by no means a special case; they come in variables as well.